# What the simplest portable way to block a thread 'forever'?

Tags: c++, portability

I have this class Foo, such that when you create an instance of it, it starts a background thread in the constructor, and the background thread runs until the destructor is called on the object instance (which sets a flag to tell the background thread to exit) and then waits for the background thread finishes.

So, I want to write a small program that runs the background thread indefinitely

```
int main(int argc, char[][] argv)
{
    Foo foo(argc, argv);

    block_forever(); // How do I implement this portably?

    return 0;
}
```

making something like ctrl-c/a signal to cause `block_forever` to return would be a nice bonus (but in general I can just kill the process)

Foo can be modeled as

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo() : m_stopFlag(false)
    {
        m_thread = StartThread(&ThreadFn, this);
        if (!m_thread) throw ...;
    }

    ~Foo()
    {
        m_stopFlag = true;
        JoinThread(m_thread);
    }

private:
    void* ThreadFn(void* threadParam)
    {
        Foo& foo(*static_cast<Foo*>(threadParam);
        try
        {
            while (!foo.m_stopFlag)
            {
                DoSomethingInteresting();
                SleepFiveSeconds();
            }

            return NULL;
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            abort();
        }
    }

    volatile bool m_stopFlag;
    THREAD_HANDLE m_thread;
};
```

So, the Foo background thread will *never* exit on it's own. It can *only* be stopped by the Foo instance destructor modifying `m_stopFlag`, and if anything goes wrong, any resulting exception will cause the process to abort.

I want to write a version of `main()` like the one above which will never (or at least not until something like a signal) reach the end of `main()`, and thus end my Foo background thread.

Foo is under my control, but I would rather not change it unless it was necessary.

Comment: `void block_forever() { while(1); }` .. that's pretty portable; works in C, Java, PHP, C++, C#, and it blocks it 4-eva!

Comment: Well, you don't really want to block a thread forever. You want to make it wait until a destructor is called. And then exit immediately. But I do not see any purpose of doing this.

Comment: Wait on a condition variable. Kick the condition variable in the destructor

Comment: That said, why? Why not just let the thread return and terminate?

Comment: @txtechhelp that's a wasted CPU core. At least put a small sleep in there.

Comment: If I reach the end of the function, it will call my Foo destructor and thus end the thread. I don't want to end the thread (possibly unless there's a signal or something like that)

Comment: Wait a sec. Have I read this wrong?  You want `main` to block until the thread in `Foo` terminates? This might just be a matter of joining the thread.

Comment: Foo doesn't expose any handle to the thread it creates, but that's a good idea

Comment: You have no control over the implementation of `Foo`? No ability to add a `WaitForDeath` function? Is there a `isFooAlive` function you can test and sleep in a loop?

Comment: `while(true) sleep(1000);`

Comment: Block what forever?

Comment: the thread hosting the foo instance on its stack

Comment: I'd have the class expose a semaphore. The main thread can block on the semaphore, which the class updates in its destructor.

Comment: Semaphore's the right idea, but it needs to be triggered on thread completion. The `Foo` destructor can't run until `main` exits. `main` can't exit because it's blocked on `Foo`. I think we need more information about `Foo`.

Comment: It's explicitly fine if we end up with a deadlock in terms of thread termination. That's what I actually want.

Comment: It's not clear from your question, do you want the "block forever" to actually unblock when the background thread ends? Please edit question to clarify yes or no to that.

Comment: The background thread only exits if the destructor is run

Comment: That has nothing to do with my question

Comment: Sorry, the answer is that the question is ill-formed, because the only way the background thread would stop is because the foreground thread was unblocked.

Comment: I vote to close as unclear what you are asking, since you do not seem to know whether the foreground thread should unblock or not

Comment: ... It shouldn't. I thought I was being clear?

Comment: I'll write some code as an example when I get home

Answer (score 1):

Likely a while loop around a wait on a condition variable is what you are looking for. The condition variable is never signalled. You still need the while loop because of spurious lookups and you need a vestigial mutex. As a bonus, when you do need to break out of the wait loop, it will be obvious how to do so. Waiting on a semaphore will also work if that abstraction is available.

That said, in any real situation, there are complications. First off, The thread abstraction may or may not be within your definition of "portable." Second, in some environments a main thread has responsibilities such as running an event loop. So this will not be entirely portable. On POSIX based systems I might just use `sigwait`.

Comment: Sigwait is ideal, but I need to support windows.

Comment: I already happen to have a portability wrapper readily available for semaphores, so I may go with that. Still interested if there's a truly portable (pre-c++11) way of doing this.

Comment: Blocking the main thread on Windows is not really a good idea. Maybe you can do it from a command line context, but really something should be calling `GetMessage` etc. in an event loop.

Comment: Also, Windows does have a POSIX subsystem. Sounds like what you are doing is different enough that it may actually be worth considering...

Comment: I've never really worked on gui-related stuff on windows, I was under the impression that a 'console' /deamon application didn't need to concern itself with 'the' message loop?